# DataFrame.apply returns DataFrame when Series (of sqlalchemy.sql.and_ values) expected

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compose a series of **sqlalchemy.sql.and_** values to pass to a **sqlalchemy.sql.or_** method in a query filter.  This seems to work most of the time, but I have one case where instead of creating a **pandas.Series**, my **df.apply** below is creating a **pandas.DataFrame**

```
s = df.apply(lambda row: and_(row[c.name] == c for c in where_cols), axis=1)
```

when I check the type's in this line, I get:

```
type(c)                 # returns sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column
type(row[c.name] == c)  # returns sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression
type(s)                 # returns pandas.DataFrame, where column headers are all c.name values
```

Downstream from my **df.apply**, the series is used as follows:

```
or_list = s.tolist()
s = session.query(
    *select_cols
).filter(
    or_(*or_list)
).statement
```

I am trying to understand why my **df.apply** is returning a DataFrame in this case.  Or, more directly, why does DataFrame.apply interpret the sqlalchemy.sql.and_ return value as multiple values?  And, how, during this interpretation, are the headers decided to be each **c.name** (column headers in this DataFrame are labeled as **c.name** in the case where the value is **row[c.name] == c**)?

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved the issue:

```
s = df.apply(lambda row: and_(wc.__eq__(row[c.name]) for c in where_cols), axis=1)
```

if someone explain the differences between the **__eq__** and **==** comparison operations as they relate to my issue via an edit to this solution, i would love to know.  thanks!